# MySQL - Check Uniqueness of Columns Values

Tags: mysql

**Is it possible to write a MySQL query to check the "uniquness" of a combination of columns?**

At the moment I have been doing this by attempting to create unique key on the columns in phpmyadmin and seeing if it fails, which is not ideal for lots of reasons.

A query could allow me to find the rows that have the duplicate values in those columns or even count how many rows are causing the combination to not be unique. It would also be nice to know how many different sets of duplicate values there are.

Example with checking columns b, c

```
a|b|c
-----
1|2|3
4|1|3
1|2|9
```

no rows for above returned even though two values are the same in b and two values are the same in c.

---

```
a|b|c
-----
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|2|3
7|5|6
```

All rows would be returned or the query could return the sets 2|3 and 5|6 .

Comment: Something is either unique, or it isn't. What's 'uniqueness'?

Comment: Your comment is unique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `select` query with `group by a,b,c` and `having count(*) > 1` will show you rows which are duplicates of other rows. To see the unique rows you can change the `having` clause to`having count(*) = 1`.

If you want to check which combinations of `b,c` are unique you can do

```
select b,c
from t1
group by b,c
having count(*) = 1
```

For example to find duplicate `a,b,c` combinations you can do:

```
select a,b,c
from t1
group by a,b,c
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You better create unique table like this and then rename as You wish:

```
CREATE TABLE table_unique AS 
(SELECT a,b,c FROM table GROUP BY a,b,c HAVING COUNT(*)=1);
```